# Can't get the secrets from Restlet Authorizer

Tags: authorization, restlet

I am using Restlet Authentication and Authorization. But I can't get the secrets in my customized enroller, it is null. Here is the code:

TestApplication.java

```
@Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot()
  {
    Router rootRouter = new Router(getContext());

    Router pubRouter = new Router(getContext());

    pubRouter.attach("/test", TestResource.class);

    RoleAuthorizer ra = new RoleAuthorizer();

    ra.getAuthorizedRoles().add(MyEnroler.PUBLISHER);

    ra.setNext(pubRouter);

    rootRouter.attach("/publish", ra);

    ChallengeAuthenticator guard = 
      new ChallengeAuthenticator(getContext(),ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "my realm");

    guard.setVerifier(new MyVerifier());

    guard.setEnroler(new MyEnroler());

    guard.setNext(rootRouter);

    return guard;
}
```

Enroller.java

```
public class MyEnroler implements Enroler
{
  public final static Role PUBLISHER = new Role("publisher", "publisher");

  public void enrole(ClientInfo clientInfo)
  {
     System.out.println(clientInfo.getUser().getIdentifier());
     System.out.println(new String(theClientInfo.getUser().getSecret()));
  }
}
```

theClientInfo.getUser().getSecret() always return null

ClientResource.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // Create a HTTP Server listening to the port 8182
    Component c = new Component();

    c.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

    c.getDefaultHost().attach("/myapp", new TestApplication());

    c.start();

    ClientResource pubResource = 


new ClientResource("http://localhost:8182/myapp/publish/test");

ChallengeResponse cr = 
  new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "scott", "tiger");

pubResource.setChallengeResponse(cr);

pubResource.get()
```

}

Does anybody know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the latest code, it does not appear that the secret is ever set on the User object.  However, you can override the verify(request, response) method in your MyVerifier class to set it, like so:

```
@Override
public int verify(Request request, Response response) {
    int result = super.verify(request, response);
    if (result == RESULT_VALID) {
        request.getClientInfo().getUser().setSecret(getSecret(request, response));
    }
    return result;
}
```